# ERRO com PDO mysql e PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Já 'descomentei' o arquivo php.ini para o PDO funcionar, reiniciei várias vezes o apache, o mysql, o notebook, mas não consigo conectar ao banco de dados MySQL.

Uso Windows 7. Pior que instalei uma maquina virtual em outro PC com UBUNTU 14 e o mesmo erro aconteceu.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que é?

O usuário e senha estão corretos, é o mesmo usuário do banco que criei.

Segue o código de conexão:

```
<?php
  try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=nomebanco user=root password=123456");

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

Erro:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

Comment: Cara, o teu erro já diz a solução: *Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)*. Apague o password, deixe somente aspas, assim:      $conexao      = new PDO('mysql:dbname=reservas;host=localhost', 'root', '',
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));

Comment: Que estranho, fiz do jeito que você falou e o mesmo erro persistiu... Muito estranho isso :/ obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Tente esse código: <?php
  try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=nomebanco; host=localhost', 'root','');

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();

}

?>

Comment: Eita, funcionou!! Acho que era erro na ordem do código ou coisa assim, usei o código que você me passou, porem, não deixei sem senha, coloquei a senha no codigo, no lugar do '', e a conexão funcionou direitinho... Cara, muito obrigado pela atenção e por ter me ajudado a solucionar o problema! Bom final de semana, até mais.

Comment: De nada, estamos ai :)